# To get distinct month name and count the values of duplicates, among multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have three tables likely `tbdata`,`tbdatahw`,`tbdatamr`. In that all tables the fields called `status` and `c42` are same. for example `tbdatahw table`[image]

like this same fields in `tbdata and tbdatamr table`. Field status 1 specifies green color and 2 for yellow and `c42` for date details. what i try achieve is in January month how many green yellow status in among all 3 tables. I tried this query in workbench

```
    SELECT  MONTHNAME(c42) MONTH, SUM( case when status = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS red
,SUM( case when status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS green
,SUM( case when status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS yellow
FROM  tbdata where  month(c42) is not null group by month(c42)
union all 
SELECT  MONTHNAME(c42) MONTH, SUM(distinct case when status = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS red
,SUM(distinct case when status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS green
,SUM(distinct case when status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS yellow
FROM  tbdatamr where  month(c42) is not null group by month(c42)
union all 
SELECT  MONTHNAME(c42) MONTH, SUM(distinct case when status = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS red
,SUM(distinct case when status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS green
,SUM(distinct case when status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS yellow
FROM  tbdatahw where  month(c42) is not null group by month(c42);
```

It is giving the output with redundancy like[image]

i don't want the February month coming two times but  i want to add the green status value from two feb into one.  I tried `distinct` and `union` as well but not working. I want the output like this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select month, 
SUM(t.red) as red, 
SUM(t.green) as green, 
SUM(t.yellow) as yellow 
from ( {put your whole query here} ) as t GROUP BY month ORDER BY FIELD(month, 'JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY',{please continue to DECEMBER})
```

Comment: Thank you man. got the answer but in that April month comes first, Is it possible to make it order by?

Comment: Updated my answer ;) > If you're happy 'cause it works, a validating action or upvote is very welcome

Comment: really happy. Gave you both :)